# how to migrate apache from 2.2.21 to 2.2.22

Tags: apache-2.2

Hello i´m trying to migrate from apache 2.2.21 to 2.2.22 on Windows 2003, but the installer file tell me, " I have to remove my actual version to install the new", that is correct ??

Answer (score 1):

Some windows installers ask to remove the old binaries. Before doing anything make sure that all apache files and sites are backed up and that the restore is working fine (test on a VM).

If you are running a VM you can make a snapshot (this days you should run inside a VM anyways).

Copy the configuration files to be easily restore-able. A restore that requires 3 teams and 2 working days of downtime is almost useless.

Then run the upgrade. Test your components and after a while remove the VM snapshot.

Comment: and new in apache, can you tell what files I have to make backup ??, or give a link to review.

Comment: You need to provide some details about the apache installation that you have. Look in the "Add Remove Programs" and see how apache was installed. Then find out if you are using php, etc... Do you have a documentation of the initial installation of the current apache?

Comment: I check on "Add Remove Programs" I have Apache HTTP Server 2.2.21, I dont have documentation, but apache was installed on D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\*.

Comment: Do you have other components that you are using? Like php.

Comment: No more components was installed